# Confused over Date use in scala.js

Tags: scala.js

I am using a a `java.util.Date` in an isomorphic class:

```
case class RendezVous(var id: Option[String], var date : Date, var lieu : String)
```

On the page the date shows like

```
{"date$1":"2015-05-06T07:10:47.433Z"}
```

Would the [`java.util.Date.scala`](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/blob/b2752e7ba140d32dbec2ed34841395d31328dccb/javalib/src/main/scala/java/util/Date.scala) not help in this matter? And if not then how can i use a Date in a jvm/js shared class

Comment: Do you call `date.toString()`? If you do, that should definitely call the implementation of `toString()` in the source that you link, which should give a relatively good output. The output you get looks as if you were calling `JSON.stringify(date)` or something.

Comment: When using `toString` it indeed shows a proper string representation. I am still confused however. Does the aforementioned `Data.scala` allow me to   access my `date` field as a JavaScript date?

Comment: You can convert a `java.util.Date` to a `js.Date` pretty easily: `new js.Date(d.getTime().toDouble)`, and that's it. In the other direction: `new java.util.Date(d.getTime().toLong)`.

Comment: Yes found that as well. Thank you. So you can't use the shared class directly, you need to add conversion code (like i am doing with `Seq -> js.Array`

Comment: @sjrd I'd suggest promoting your comment to an answer.

Comment: @SimeonFitch Done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert a `java.util.Date` to a `js.Date` pretty easily:

```
new js.Date(d.getTime().toDouble)
```

and that's it. In the other direction:

```
new java.util.Date(d.getTime().toLong)
```